# Upgrading to a new graphics card, any tips?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I am willing to get a new graphics card - Nvidia GTX 950.
I currently have the Nvidia GT 730. The last time I tried installing the new graphics card's drivers I had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.
Does anyone have any tips on installing the GTX 950's drivers?

**My current specs are:**

- Memory: 12 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4
- Graphics: GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2
- OS type: 64-bit
- Disk: 296 GB

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do anything. Both adaters are supported by the same proprietary drivers.

Make sure that the latest proprietary driver is installed and replace the card.

In Ubuntu 16.04 it is `nvidia-367`.